# Is there a Python library that eases the creation of CLI utilities like Django management commands?

Tags: python, django, command-line

I want to create a set of command-line utilities in python that would be used like so:

```
python utility.py command1 -option arg
```

Very similar to django management commands. Is there any library that eases the creation of such commands?

Comment: You could also use Django's management system very easily in your project.

Comment: @rebos Yes, this is what I typically do for my own scripting needs that involve database access for the past 2 years. And that is the reason why I'm taking the django management system as a reference when asking this question. I need this for an opensource project idea I want to develop and I don't want to impose django as a library requirement for the project and setting up a  django project as a requirement for the commands to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Baker](http://bitbucket.org/mchaput/baker) is rather nice I think. [Optfunc](http://github.com/simonw/optfunc) maybe also.

Answer (score 2):

[Optparse is the way to go](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [plac](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=294291). I haven't used it as I stumbled to it just recently. It looks simple enough, though.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to create a two-level command?  You should use [argparse](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/) -- it's simple enough, is similar to optparse but makes the two-level command thing easy, and will be in the standard library with Python 2.7.